Power Apps no Auth Requirement
I got a app made in Power Apps and I need to share with random people. It's like a form and my first thought was to use Microsoft Forms but that people have to sign at the final of the form and Microsoft Froms doesn't give me that kind of functionality. So instead I used Power Apps for that reason. The problem is that the person have to use a Microsoft Account to fill the form in power apps. I was looking different kinds of "solutions" but none works at the moment. Someome knows a way to avoid that auth and anyone can use my app?.
One of the solutions was use Azure AD B2C and guest users, but the problem:

Random peolple are gonna use the app.
Give access one by one is the word solution o way to solve this.

So, again. is there a way to avoid this auth requirement in power apps?
